# Combine two sbytes into int

Tags: c#, byte

I have two bytes. how ever i must combine this two bytes by ignoring most significant bit of each byte.

In fact two bytes are signed bytes. so i have to ignore Most significant bits and concatenate 7 remaining bits.

Here is my code with simple example. I get the last 7 bits of each byte. then i left shift first byte by 7 and add the second byte. however it does not give the correct result.

```
byte b1 = 131; // 10000011
byte b2 = 96;  // 01100000

//Ignoring most significant bit and get 7 remaining bits.
byte t1 = (byte) (b1 & 127); // 0000011 in 8-bits saved as 00000011
byte t2 = (byte) (b2 & 127); // 1100000 in 8-bits saved as 01100000

// Left shift first byte by 7. and add the second byte
// t1:  00000011 0000000
// t2:         0 1100000  +
//      00000011 1100000  =
int ut1t2 = t1 << 7 + t2; // 480 is expected but it gives 384
```

Comment: To do bitwise operations, use `|`. `+` is meant for arithmetics. And use `b1 & 0x7f` to make the intent clearer, as you can see the real binary value to act on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a wrong result because [`<<` has lower precedence then `+`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx). You can do it with `|` without brackets (bitwise OR is more common than `+` when operating on bits)

```
int ut1t2 = t1 << 7 | t2;
```

Or even do it in one line, like this:

```
int ut1t2 = ((b1 & 127) << 7) | (b2 & 127);
```

Comment: thanks. i think im going to use `|` operator. seems cleaner. also is there any performance difference between + and | ?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary On modern CPUs there would be no difference. Even older CPUs would use lookahead adders to do addition in a single cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Missing brackets :(

```
int ut1t2 = (t1 << 7) + t2; // returns 480!
```

What you had was equivalent to:

```
int ut1t2 = t1 << (7 + t2);
```

Comment: oh. i feel stupid now! i didnt know + operator has more priority than <<. thanks!